# No se actualiza la opción del producto consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

esta consulta solo me actualiza una vez la columna opciones

```
UPDATE productos SET opciones = (CASE
WHEN ID = '1' THEN '[
{"name":"Talla: 34","precio":"59000","stock":3,"sku":"1273-34"},
{"name":"Talla: 35","sku":"1273","precio":"59000","stock":10}
]'
WHEN ID = '1' THEN '[
{"name":"Talla: 34","precio":"59000","stock":3,"sku":"1273-34"},
{"name":"Talla: 35","sku":"1273","precio":"59000","stock":7}
]'
END) WHERE ID IN (('1'))
```

pero si funciona con distintos ID pero cuando es el mismo ID con varias opciones no se actualizan completas solo la primera opción.

Por que ocurre ?

Comment: La pregunta es: ¿por qué estás usando los `WHEN` con el mismo id? Acordate que el `CASE` funciona como un `IF ... ELSIF`.

Comment: @padaleiana ahora ya entiendo gracias por tu comentario es cierto que la sentencia CASE termina cuando se completa  la condición como verdadera y las otra quedaran pasadas por alto lo hice pensando que eran recurrentes.